# Is there ever a good reason to leave an html tag open?

Tags: html

So I'm pretty sure the answer to this is `no, don't do this`, but im curious if there is some special case where this might be useful.

I'v found in the past if I accidentally leave a `<div>` without a closing `</div>` and close the div's parent instead(if the parent is of a different type like a `<td>` for instance), when the page is rendered the DOM picks up the slack and closes the div for me. This is something I would expect a syntax highlighter to pick up but mine at least doesn't bark at me if something like this happens, which makes me think there might be a niche use for this, but I might be thinking too deeply into something that is just an example of bad code.

An example would be

```
<td id="table_cell">
    <div class="tc_wrapper">
         <div id="tc_content1"> ... </div>
         <div id="tc_content2"> ... </div>
         <div id="tc_content3"> ... </div>
         <div id="tc_content4"> ... </div>
<!-- this is where u would normally close tc_wrapper
    </div>
-->
</td>
```

Note: I'm dyslexic and have to depend pretty heavily on syntax highlighting to make sure heavily nested things are correctly closed and ordered which is why this scenario tends to happen...

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the browser to compensate for an unclosed div. Typically if I have a display that is broken this is the very first thing I look for. I highly recommend you use a code editor that supports auto tag closing, code folding, and shows visually how your code indentation lines up. I can't make a specific recommendation here, but there are many out there that do all of this.

Answer (score 0):

No. Better to close everything off unless it's closing tag is itself such as `<img />`. It will improve debugging later down the line or if you need to improve your code.